# No resource found that matches the given name '@style/ Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android

My Android Manifiest

uses-sdk

```
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
```

values-v11:
    
    
        
    

values-v14:

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

The problem is I'm getting an error on bith values-v14(Styles.xml) and 
values-v11(styles.xml) I am new in android. Thanx in advance

Comment: Your `minSdkVersion` is 8 but `Theme.holo.light.darkActionBar` requires that to be 14. Either change your `minSdkVersion` or user some other theme.

Comment: which theme i can use then?

Comment: also i face the same problem in Values-v11.
My value-v11 is
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current minSdkVersion is 8. Either change it to 14+ or use AppCompat support library. This library will let you draw action in lower APIs also.

Inside style tag you will have to use `Theme.AppCompat.light` as parent.

Comment: i set my target to 14 bt now i show me erro on
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>

Comment: try using AppCompat support library